# Add Trees to Terrain C# with TreeInstance

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I try to add trees to my terrain with the following code:

```
// Create Trees
for (int x = 0; x < terrainData.heightmapWidth; x++)
{
    for (int z = 0; z < terrainData.heightmapWidth; z++)
    {
        if (GetBiome(x, z) == "Grasland")
        {
            int r = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 500);
            if (r == 0)
            {
                Terrain terrain = GetComponent<Terrain>();
                TreeInstance treeTemp = new TreeInstance();
                treeTemp.position = new Vector3(x, 0, z);
                treeTemp.prototypeIndex = 0;
                treeTemp.widthScale = 1f;
                treeTemp.heightScale = 1f;
                treeTemp.color = Color.white;
                treeTemp.lightmapColor = Color.white;
                terrain.AddTreeInstance(treeTemp);
                terrain.Flush();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the function `GetBiome()` works correctly, i checked that by placing the trees as GameObjects and it worked fine.

Is there something missing that i didn't thought of?

Because there's not a single tree generated.

The tree i want to generate is set up under PaintTrees:

[image]

Comment: Attach VS debugger to Unity and place breakpoints, check the spelling, I noticed "Grasland" may have been intended as Grassland etc. (is this case-sensitive also?) and finally if you don't feel comfortable debugging, use the built-in Debug.Log method and look at the console to see what is happening, hope that helps.

Comment: @aaronedmistone like i wrote the "Gralsand" thing works fine, i used the exact same code for placing trees as GameObjects, there is 100% no wrong spelling or something.

Comment: @aaronedmistone i also just tested it without the biome check, it doesn't work either.

Comment: Is it possible that it's never getting inside of the `if (r == 0)` block? What's so unique about `0` that you seem to be arbitrarily checking against it? Try removing the if statement and see if it any gets generated -- It is random after all.

Comment: @Chris tried that, but didn't work

Comment: Great, 
I've noticed a few things, your line:`for (int z = 0; z < terrainData.heightmapWidth; z++)` should be `heightMapHeight` not width.

Also I've read that the position expected is local to the terrain and expects a value between 0 and 1. You could achieve this with `treeTemp.position = new Vector3(x / terrainData.heightmapWidth, 0, z / terrainData.heightmapHeight);`

 I would still strongly recommend 
`Debug.Log("Placed Tree");` 
or similar when placing.

Comment: @aaronedmistone okay i tried that and i also added a Debug.Log("Create tree at " + x + " / " + y); and i got a lot of Debug Messages that the trees get placed, but there are still no trees. I also changed everything you mentioned.

Comment: @aaronedmistone okay so now i've seen that all trees get spawned at 0/0?!

Comment: okay i think i found the problem: its because of x and z are ints. i changed it to ((float)x / (float)terrainData.heightmapWidth) and it works.

Comment: Yes, please see my answer below explaining that. Please accept my answer if the answer worked for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read my notes as comments below, I hope this explains and resolves the issue.
I have tested this in unity to confirm.

```
// Create Trees

//make these float otherwise your position math below is truncated
for (float x = 0; x < terrainData.heightmapWidth; x++)
{
    //heightmapHeight not heightmapWidth
    for (float z = 0; z < terrainData.heightmapHeight; z++)
    {
        Terrain terrain = GetComponent<Terrain>();
        int r = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 500);
        if (r == 0)
        {
            TreeInstance treeTemp = new TreeInstance

            //position is local and expects value between 0 and 1
            treeTemp.position = new Vector3(x / terrainData.heightmapWidth, 0, z / terrainData.heightmapHeight),

            treeTemp.prototypeIndex = 0;
            treeTemp.widthScale = 1f;
            treeTemp.heightScale = 1f;
            treeTemp.color = Color.white;
            treeTemp.lightmapColor = Color.white;
            terrain.AddTreeInstance(treeTemp);
            terrain.Flush();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but, instead of

```
int r = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 500);
        if (r == 0)
```

do

```
int r = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 500);
        if (r >= 0 && <= 1)
```

to check for range. Because you're checking for a impossible number it will always come close but never 0 for example 0.000230...f you will need to Math floor it or check for range like I did